# How can I create a dynamic overlay for a UIButton?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

My application has a few portions that have really big buttons (640x130, 230x150, etc.)  What I need is to have a way to update different portions of the button, with different text.  Initially, I assumed that in my code I could create various UILabels and then add them as subviews to my button.  However, as soon as I try to add a UILabel to the button as a sub-view, my app crashes.

What is the easiest way to create an overlay for a button, that I can completely layout myself, without preventing button taps from being interested using overlay controls?

I imagine there are multiple ways to solve this problem.  However, the best solution for my case should use the fewest lines of code (I have quite a few of these types of buttons) and I'd like to be able to continue using some form of configurable button within IB.

I'm not opposed to subclassing UIButton but, if I do, I would like to be able to use it in IB.  I've never created a custom UIView for such a circumstance, so I'd need help defining that type of subclass so that it will work correctly in IB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the subview to the containing view - not the button.  To ensure that is doesn't interfere with button presses, be sure to set it to:

```
[myCustomTextOverlay setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```